# Is viscosity caused by 'electric charge interaction' between molecules, or its just like friction and caused by 'roughness' of molecular structure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

When I hear that viscosity is the "internal frictional force between layers of fluid", Iam being guided to imagine the usual friction where a rough surface's irregularities are hindering the motion.
But, in case of liquids, its the molecular interactions that are holding all the stuff together. And I always feel like the molecular interaction must be what should cause any 'hinderance to motion'.

But the roughness idea doesnt sound that bad either, it feels like structure of molecules could affect the flow or motion of the fluid.

So which one is it?
Is it both?

Comment: Neither.  It is caused by momentum transfer between faster- and slower moving layers due to collisions between molecules in these layers.

Answer (score 2):

Roughness of the molecular structure at the microscopic level just refers to the columbic repulsion/attraction of these molecules to other molecules which move through the fluid. So internal friction is just caused by the attraction between two molecules pulling them out when they move due to an external force .
Hence I think both the terms are the same!

Comment: Naveen is correct that both friction and viscosity are electronic in nature, however, the fundamental nature of their causes can be different, and in fact, even "viscosity" can look different. The viscosity of air, water, and molasses have different primary drivers, although in all cases the force is due to EM.

Comment: Yes, there's a difference between a molecule gettting in the way of another molecule and experiencing electrostatic force and getting its motion hindered (kind of friction), vs. a molecule moving 'nearby' another molecule and experiencing electrostatic force (cohesion force). Both are ultimately same type of force, but their magnitude, direction etc are of quite different types.

Comment: @RohitShekhawat I kind of agree but even the cohesion force differs with the position where it is happening albeit both are the same type

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest model for calculating the viscosity of fluids in shear flow, the pure collisions between particles transfers momentum, witch diffuses between layers of fluid with different velocities relative to each other.

For instance in Reif's ***Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics***
Chap 13.5 *Example: calculation of viscosity*

In collisions the particles interact by electromagnetic forces and exchange interaction from quantum mechanics may play a role.

Comment: What about The lowest layer of fluid(which is in contact with the surface below)? Is it also slowed by collision with the rough surface of the ground, or by adhesion of the water-ground molecules?

Comment: Can you answer on this related question of mine - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/752048/will-the-velocity-gradient-be-zero-if-there-is-no-adhesive-attraction-with-the-b