# Will the velocity gradient be zero if there is no adhesive attraction with the bottom surface?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, flow, viscosity

[image: Viscosity]

(Above is a representation of what I currently understand of viscosity).

My question is, if the bottom layer and the floor didnt interact with adhesive forces and hence the motion of bottom layer of liquid was not slowed(or stopped), then the motion of upper layers wont be hindered either. As a result, all the layers will flow at same rate i.e same velocity of all layers.

Is this correct assumption?

Does this mean that viscosity will also be zero in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This looks as two free boundaries, which is indeed difficult to realize for a fluid like it is shown in your drawing.

Flow with one free boundary occurs in open channels. The flow is still a shear-flow due to the no-slip boundary condition at the ground.
A free boundary all around the fluid is for example the case if the water is streaming out of a faucet.
The interaction with the surrounding air is nearly negligible.

But the viscosity still remains. This is a material constant of the fluid. What depends from the boundary is the shearing- that is different velocities of adjacent fluid layers.

Comment: Im also reffering to the 'open channels'. What im asking is that if there is no 'adhesive' interaction of water with the bottom surface of channel, then the bottom layer of water will not have any hinderance in its motion. would it? If it would, then will all layers flow with same speed?

Comment: I'm sorry, but now I can only cite. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-slip_condition . This means exceptions from the No-slip-condition are imaginable but rare. But if there where no adhesive stress from the bottom, you where right.